# Regex escaping meta characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches:

if([any contents])

So far I have:

```
if([*])
```

However, I am falling down because "(" and ")" are meta characters and need to be escaped - but how?

Comment: Usually with a backslash: `\(` and `\)`, but if you're using some weird tool, the syntax might be different. Also, `[*]` matches literally one single asterisk, I think you want `.*` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
if\([^\]]*\)
```

`(`, `)` are regex meta characters which was actually used to refer the start and end of a capturing group. So you need to escape the brackets inorder to match the literal `(`, `)` symbols.